# Extended glob can't retrace behaviour

Tags: bash

I looked at a bash guide where I found this example:
http://guide.bash.academy/expansions/

> ```
> $ ls !(my*).txt # All the .txt files that do not begin with my.
>
> hello.txt
>
> $ ls !(my)*.txt # Can you guess why this one matches myscript.txt?
>
> myscript.txt
> hello.txt
> ```

I'm familiar with basic concepts of `regular expressions` maybe this is confusing me because I'm trying to apply those concepts to `extended globs` in bash.

I do not understand why `!(my)*.txt` is expanding `myscript.txt` in `bash`. The explanation in the guide does not help me at all.

My reasoning:

- `!(my*).txt` does not match `myscript.txt` because it does start with `my` then matches the rest of the characters `script` and at the end it matches .txt
- `!(my)*.txt` **does not (wrong!!!)**   match `myscript.txt` because it is starting with `my` followed by any characters and at the end it matches `.txt`

Where am I wrong in my argumentation?

Comment: @Cyrus I know  -  I poorly worded that => updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common gotcha with wildcards. The question to ask yourself is, is there any way to split up `myscript.txt` such that the first piece matches `!(my)` and the second matches `*.txt`?

The answer is, counter-intuitively, yes: If you "split" `"myscript.txt"` into `""` (the empty string) and `"myscript.txt"` then the empty string matches `!(my)` and `"myscript.txt"` matches `*.txt`. **The empty string is a valid match!**